# Two jQuery Mobile sliders working together

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to have 2 sliders in a JQM site which affect each other.

Slider 1 will change the number of months
Slider 2 will change the cost

Behind the scenes, there will be an amount, say $3600

By default, the number of months slider will be 36, therefore the cost slider would be $10

If the user changes the months slider to be 18, the cost slider should auto-change to $20 (since 20 * 18 = £3600)

Likewise, if the user changes the cost slider to $20, the months slider should move to 18 months.

I added a bind("onchange") to both sliders but ended up with a "Maximum callsize stack exceeded" error.

I have tried using event.originalEvent and event.preventDefault but to no avail.

How would I go about getting these 2 to work with each other so that if 1 is updated, the other also recalculates and vice versa?

Thanks

Comment: If you bind `change` event handlers to both elements you'll get an infinite loop, since each event handler changes the value of the other input... One input changes another, that one's event handler runs (changing the first input) which triggers the first input's event handler, and so on

Comment: Hi Jesper, yeah I gathered that was the reason - is there a way round this though?

Answer (score 0):

The refresh seems to be the thing that triggers the change event so now I die() the event before calling refresh, then create it again

```
$("#Months").val(42);
// remove binding
$("#Months").die("change");
$("#Months").slider("refresh");
$("#Months").live("change", ChangeMonths);
```

Seems to work, maybe not pretty but oh well